Subclass method override not assignable to same property in base type when returning super
Say I want to extend the Promise class with an overriden then() method that does something before calling super.then():
class ExtendedPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
  then(...x: Parameters<InstanceType<typeof Promise<T>>["then"]>) {
    console.log("Do something here");
    return super.then(...x);
  }
}

Playground
TypeScript complains that this override is not assignable to the same property in the base type because unknown is not assignable to type TResult1 | TResult2, but how is that possible? I'm accepting the same parameters as the parent type and literally returning the return value of super, so the types should all be identical?

Unrelated to the problem, but you should simplify InstanceType<typeof Promise<T>> to Promise<T>

IIRC this and similar problems are caused by trying to override (or call) a generic method with multiple overloads. Look at the declaration of then in Promise

That's because Promise's then method has generics that might be independent from Promise's generic type, since you are not providing these generics for then function, it's taking the default generic types which are <T, never>, you can have a workaround by statically typing the function parameter's types and adding <TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never> after then, because i can't find a way give the then in the string index the generic types, for example, what you want in this case is this:
class ExtendedPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(...x: Parameters<InstanceType<typeof Promise<T>>["then"]<TResult1, TResult2>>) { // this does not work unfortunately
        console.log("Do something");
        return super.then(...x);
    }
}

Unfortunately it does not work.
If you decide to statically type the params here's the code
class ExtendedPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | null | undefined) {
        console.log("Do something");
        return super.then(onfulfilled, onrejected);
    }
}

